# How to create self loop in igraph R?

Tags: r, igraph

How to add `self loop` to a graph beside changing `Adjacency matrix` which is changing `c(i,i)=1`, is there a function to do that  in `igraph` `R` package?

**Edit** : graph creation :

```
  network=read.csv(file.choose())
  network[,1]=as.character(network[,1]) 
  network[,2]=as.character(network[,2])
  mygraph=graph.data.frame(network,directed=TRUE)
  E(mygraph)$weight=as.numeric(network[,3])
```

**reproducible** example :

```
karate <- graph.famous("Zachary")
E(karate)$weight <- 2
adjacency<-get.adjacency(karate, 
              attr="weight", edges=FALSE, names=TRUE)
for (i in 1:vcount(karate)){
      adjacency[i,i]<-1
    }
karate2<-graph.adjacency(adjacency, mode="directed", weighted=TRUE)
```

I am looking for a faster and easier solution, mayebe a function to do that.

Comment: Can you create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? What exactly are you talking about here? Do you want to create a self loop for every existing vertex? How did you create the graph in the first place?

Comment: Would something as simple as `library(igraph); test <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(one=1:2,two=2:1))` do for a base for further exploring?

Comment: @MrFlick, yes I want to create a self loop for every existing vertex.please see the edit part

Comment: @academic.user - your example isn't reproducible, because we don't have your file. Please see my comment as an example of a simple graph that is reproducible as a standalone item.

Comment: @thelatemail,this code will not gives us graph with self loops

Comment: @academic.user - I know that, but it is a basic graph to which you could add self-loops, hence answering your question.

Comment: @thelatemail, I added a graph to my question, but the case is I am looking for a function which adds self loops to every node.

Comment: @MrFlick, I added a graph, but is it what you asked for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a self-loop for each vertex in the `karate` example, just do

```
karate[from=V(karate), to=V(karate)] <- 1
```

This will give you

[image]